# How to create a list element which counts as a element but it should not have any value and while sorting the list it should be at last

Tags: python, list

**How to create a list element which counts as element but dont have any value for its own, and also if we wanna sort that list that no value elements should go to last**

**How to create a list like this [1,2,_]**

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        for i in range(0,len(nums)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
                if nums[i] == nums[j]:
                    nums[i] = None
                    nums.sort(key=lambda e: (e is None, e))
                    break
        return set(nums)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler without looping:

```
res = [i if i not in nums[:n] else None for n, i in enumerate(nums)]
res.sort(key=lambda e: (e is None, e))
return res
```